# How can I monitor a VS Code extension to ensure my code/files are not being sent to a remote server?

Tags: privacy, visual-studio-code

I use Copilot from GitHub and started thinking about how code that I write is sent to their remote servers to be enhanced through AI.

Is there an extension for Visual Studio Code that will monitor other extensions' activity?

I realized I can use tools like [HTTP Toolkit](https://httptoolkit.com/), [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to monitor network activity, but is there a better tool optimized for VS Code? Of course the extension's source code can be analyzed, but that can take quite some time to parse.

I just don't want my text/code/data to be sent to some sketchy third-party which I accidentally let happen because I installed an extension.

A quick search of the extensions using "extension sniffer", "extension monitor", "extension network" did not return any relevant results.